# Custom stock for variable products WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce, stock

I tried this function to make a custom stock status for variable products in WooCommerce but doesn`t work

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_availability', 'custom_get_availability', 1, 2);
function custom_get_availability( $availability, $product ) {
    // Only for variable products
    if ( $product->is_type( 'variable' ) ) {
        // Get the stock status of the product
        $stock_status = $product->get_stock_status();
 
        // Custom stock status
        if( $stock_status == 'outofstock' ) {
            $availability['availability'] = __('Custom Out of Stock Message', 'woocommerce');
        }
    }
    return $availability;
}
```

Comment: "Doesn't work" does not work for us, as a problem description. Please go read [ask].

Answer (score 0):

```
add_filter('woocommerce_out_of_stock_message', 'change_variable_out_of_stock_availability', 10, 1);

function change_variable_out_of_stock_availability($out_of_stock_message) {
    return __('Custom Out of Stock Message', 'woocommerce');
}
```

WooCommerce has the template for variable product `single-product/add-to-cart/variable.php`.This template can be overridden by copying it to yourtheme/woocommerce/single-product/add-to-cart/variable.php. Or this message can be altered with the dedicated hook (`woocommerce_out_of_stock_message`) for the variable product out-of-stock message

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please edit your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.